# Increase DDR memory out of motherboard, i.e. USB?

Tags: linux, memory

I have a PowerPC...
this PowerPC need to get a memory upgrade
but, all ddr2 slots are busy.

so, HOW TO INCREASE THIS RAM WITH A EXTERNAL DDR?

note:

> 1) I don't need to use ssd, or flash drivers, they are very slow!
>   2) I have heard both express mini, and express card, can i accomplish this, with it?
>   3) Are There any ddr2 usb adpaters?
>   4) If not, Using the memory of another PC over the network, it will work?

I like to use tmpfs, this is very quickly, but use  a lot of mem, thanks for all aswer, and sorry my bad english.

Comment: Just added a tag to point out that a PowerPC is made by Apple, thus unlikely to use Windows.

Comment: yeah! but the powerpc that i'm using, is made by IBM, Sony and Toshiba ;D

Answer (score 8):

Don't!

If you are using all the slots, then the best option for you is to upgrade your existing sticks to higher capacities.

Anything else is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Not to mention a "ddr2 usb adpater" would be detrimental to performance anyways. The memory's speed would be limited by the speed of USB (likely 2.0 == 480Mbit/s).

Comment: +1 agreed! I didn't go in to technical details but that comes under "Asking for trouble!"...! At the end of the day, he may be thinking of things such as ReadyBoost/ReadyDrive on Windows, but IMHO, when you look at the performance and price, you are just better off getting memory instead.

Comment: Okey the speedy of usb is very slow rather than ddr 2 slots, but i'm looking for latency performance, and is not more quickly than ddr2..

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are speaking of system RAM ("DDR2 memory").

If you find SSD and flash drives 'too slow' you're not going to find anything faster, especially not via USB - and even still the best those could be used for (aside from storage memory) is a cache system (see [Windows ReadyBoost](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-vista/features/readyboost.aspx) for an example).

You're best bet is probably to figure out what kind of motherboard you're using, and/or the specific RAM is uses, and see if there are bigger modules you can get to replace what's already in there (check with www.kingston.com).

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your memory.

Install a card that takes ddr of some flavor, and plugs into a drive port, and use it for swap (that is as close as you are going to get to more memory).

Use an external drive for swap.

Use an exported network file system for swap, or a raw device (iscsi or nbd).

If you cannot increase the memory, all you can do is add swap, and make that as fast as possible.